# dynamic pre filled value in primefaces in drop down list doesn't work

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, ajaxform

I have 3 drop down columns: Expense Type, PO Order & Position.
I am trying to make them pre-filled using AJAX, But it is not working.

```
<p:column id="expenseTypeExpenseCol" headerText="Expense Type">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="expenseTypes"
        value="#{expenseSheet.selectedExpenseType}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Expense Type" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{expenseSheet.expenseTypeItems}" />
        <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{timeAndExpenseManagedController.populateExpensePoNumber}"
            update="expenseSheet" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>

 <p:column id="bestellungExpenseCol" headerText="Purchase Order">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="bestelungExpenseSheet"
        value="#{expenseSheet.selectedPoNumber}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select PoNumber" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{expenseSheet.expSelectItems}" />
        <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{timeAndExpenseManagedController.populateExpensePos}"
            update="expenseSheet" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>

<p:column id="expensePosCol" headerText="Pos.">
    <p:selectOneMenu id="expensePos" 
     value="#{expenseSheet.lineItem}" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Pos" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{expenseSheet.poLineItemFormList}"
            var="poLine" itemLabel="#{poLine.lineItem}"
            itemValue="#{poLine.lineItem}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" 
            listener="#{timeAndExpenseManagedController.poExpenseValueChanged}" 
            update="expenseSheet" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
```

And want to make these fields pre-filled, every column should display the first item as default,

and for that I am removing f:selectItem tags, but with this the columns does show the 1st values, but it didn't populate the rest of the items in the subsequent columns.

for ex, if the values showing in Expense Type column is flight, and with that Expense Type I am not able to choose any other PO Order from the next column, as it's not populating any list in PO Order column.
But it does work fine with the current code with f:selectItem tags.

Comment: Start by making an [mcve]... This code is impossible for us to use and pinpoint to a problem

Comment: So it works if you remove the `p:ajax` tags? It works if just using one column? instead of 3? And the comlums need a datatable or something and a backingbean (where the values come from).... please read [mcve] carefully.

Comment: @Kukeltje, it doesn't work without ajax, and yes it does work for single column. the values are updated in backing bean with ajax call,  for example when Expense Type is selected,  populateExpensePoNumber method does set the expSelectItems for the Purchase Order column.

Comment: So the ajax tags in the (not)[mcve] can be removed. Ok... And if it works with one column (column, not row) than that is very strange... very...